# get auth/argument-error with next-firebase-auth

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, next.js

## Problems:

I get the error below when I tried to login using firebase auth. Everything is fine when I login using firebase auth emulator, but it presents error when using without using the auth emulator. I have also received a `500 response from login API endpoint: {"error":"Unexpected error."}` from browser console, which I presume the error is highly related with next-firebase-auth.

```
FirebaseAuthError: `uid` argument must be a non-empty string uid.
at FirebaseAuthError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (D:\Alston\Programming\Personal-Project\netflix-clone\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\error.js:44:28)
at FirebaseAuthError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (D:\Alston\Programming\Personal-Project\netflix-clone\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\error.js:90:28)
at new FirebaseAuthError (D:\Alston\Programming\Personal-Project\netflix-clone\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\error.js:149:16)
at FirebaseTokenGenerator.createCustomToken (D:\Alston\Programming\Personal-Project\netflix-clone\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\auth\token-generator.js:101:19)
at Auth.BaseAuth.createCustomToken (D:\Alston\Programming\Personal-Project\netflix-clone\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\auth\base-auth.js:87:36)
at D:\Alston\Programming\Personal-Project\netflix-clone\node_modules\next-firebase-auth\build\index.node.js:2:22240
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at asyncGeneratorStep (D:\Alston\Programming\Personal-Project\netflix-clone\node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:3:24)
at _next (D:\Alston\Programming\Personal-Project\netflix-clone\node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:25:9)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
 errorInfo: {
   code: 'auth/argument-error',
   message: '`uid` argument must be a non-empty string uid.'
 },
   codePrefix: 'auth'
 }
```

I have set up my `/api/login` page exactly as the *[official example](https://github.com/gladly-team/next-firebase-auth/blob/main/example/pages/api/login.js)*. I have tried using `signInWithEmailAndPassword` and `signInWithPopup` *(which using Google to authenticate)*, both did success to login as `console.log(results)` shows the user credentials and I can also find the relevant data in `indexed DB` too.

#### Versions of the packages

- `"next-firebase-auth": "^1.0.0-canary.5"`
- `"firebase-admin": "^10.0.2",`
- `"firebase": "^9.6.1",`

The main issues was with [login page](https://github.com/AlstonChan/Netflix-clone/blob/main/pages/login.js), and here's the
[Github Repo](https://github.com/AlstonChan/Netflix-clone).

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Yeah, I just added the GitHub repo with an edit.

Comment: Can you just copy the part that is causing issue here or provide a direct link to that perhaps?

Comment: Probably [Line 17 - 73 and 91 - 96](https://github.com/AlstonChan/Netflix-clone/blob/main/pages/login.jshttps://github.com/AlstonChan/Netflix-clone/blob/main/pages/login.js) and [initAuth](https://github.com/AlstonChan/Netflix-clone/blob/main/lib/initAuth.js)

Comment: This is the second time that I stumble upon this error, so I'm leaving a comment for the third time I fall in :D :

The issue was that in the `auth.tsx` page I was missing the `appPageURL` field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution on **[github](https://github.com/gladly-team/next-firebase-auth/issues/184)**, remove the `FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:9099` in your `.env.local` file, and everythings is back on track again, what a weird problem.